# Bluetooth device automatically disconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth

I don't know actually it is right platform to ask this question or not.

I am using the broadcast receiver to check whether the Bluetooth device is connected or not.

using following code.

```
  //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBG5Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String bg5Tag="Bluetooth";
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.e("Device state",Integer.toString(device.getBondState()));
            Log.i("Action is ",action);

            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is now connected
                Log.d(bg5Tag,"Action connected");
                Log.e("Device name ",device.getName());

            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //Done searching
                Log.d(bg5Tag,"Action searching");
                Log.e("Device name ",device.getName());

            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is about to disconnect
                Log.d(bg5Tag,"Action about disconnect");
                Log.e("Device name ",device.getName());

            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device has disconnected
                Log.d(bg5Tag,"Action disconnected");
                Log.e("Device name ",device.getName());
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)){
                Log.d(bg5Tag,"Action pairing request");
                Log.e("Device name ",device.getName());
            }
        }
    };
```

But when I tap on the device to pair **then device disconnected automatically.** But it moved to paired devices list. Why it is disconnecting?